# MAC Address Filtering on ADSL Wifi Router: DLink 2730U

Tags: wireless-networking, mac, router, wireless-router

In the past I remember setting up MAC Address filtering pretty easily by just setting the WiFi Router's default policy to Deny and then add specific MAC addresses of trusted devices.

But in my new DLink Router the MAC filtering interface seems to have changed (see screenshot below). Now it seems to have outgoing and incoming rules sections.

So how do I set trusted devices here. Must I set the rule twice? Once for incoming packets and once for outgoing packets?

Do I just leave the Destination blank for Outgoing and Source Blank for Incoming? Or is it a '*' wildcard? The help does not seem to say much.

Or is it enough to leave one policy permissive (outgoing / incoming) and just filter by MAC addresses on the other?

Any suggestions?[image]

Comment: MAC address filtering is a joke. It is beyond easy to find and spoof a trusted MAC address. If you rely on this for security, then you are just fooling yourself.

Comment: @RonMaupin No, not relying on it. I already have WPA2-AES set up. Is it redundant to add Mac address filtering after that? Or is it another layer that may help?

Comment: MAC addresses are sent in the clear, even with encryption. It is a lot of work, with almost no gain. Most people just don't bother. It is the same with trying to hide your SSID; it is simply not effective. Your efforts would be better spent getting a RADIUS server and using that with WPA2.

Comment: @RonMaupin Thanks. I thought RADIUS was for centralized key management. Is using RADIUS fundamentally more secure than just sharing a key (passphrase)? I'm using a 10+ character passphrase.